# Replacing observations to NA from tsibble based on date range

Tags: r, tidyverse, tsibble

I have this following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tsibble)

time <- c("2020 01", "2020 02", "2020 03", "2020 04", "2020 05", "2020 06",
          "2020 01", "2020 02", "2020 03", "2020 04", "2020 05", "2020 06",
          "2020 01", "2020 02", "2020 03", "2020 04", "2020 05", "2020 06",
          "2020 01", "2020 02", "2020 03", "2020 04", "2020 05", "2020 06")
state <- c(rep("CA", 6), rep("PA", 6), rep("NY", 6), rep("WI", 6))
values <- rnorm(24)

dataf <- data.frame(time, state, values)

dataf <- dataf %>%
  mutate(time = yearmonth(time)) %>%
  as.data.frame()

dataf_tsible <- as_tsibble(dataf, index = time, key = state)
```

Now, I want to remove the values in the variable values from March to May 2020.

This works:

```
dataf_tsible$values[dataf_tsible$time== yearmonth("2020 Mar")] <- NA
dataf_tsible$values[dataf_tsible$time== yearmonth("2020 Apr")] <- NA
dataf_tsible$values[dataf_tsible$time== yearmonth("2020 May")] <- NA
```

But is there any better and more efficient way to do that without changing the time class?

Comment: wait, when you say 'without changing the time class', do you mean when you did yearmonth(time)?

Comment: Could you confirm whether you  want to "remove the values" or "replace the values with NA"? The question may be ambiguous?

Comment: @Mark I want to make sure the data is in tsibble class. That's it.

Comment: @Peter Replace by NA. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Could you please update the question title and text to reflect that you wish to replace selected values by NA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could carryout a `mutate`  to replace selected values with `NA` prior to creating the `tsibble`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tsibble)

set.seed(42)

time <- c("2020 01", "2020 02", "2020 03", "2020 04", "2020 05", "2020 06",
          "2020 01", "2020 02", "2020 03", "2020 04", "2020 05", "2020 06",
          "2020 01", "2020 02", "2020 03", "2020 04", "2020 05", "2020 06",
          "2020 01", "2020 02", "2020 03", "2020 04", "2020 05", "2020 06")
state <- c(rep("CA", 6), rep("PA", 6), rep("NY", 6), rep("WI", 6))
values <- rnorm(24)

dataf <- 
  data.frame(time, state, values) |> 
  mutate(time = yearmonth(time),
         values = ifelse(between(time, yearmonth("2020 Mar"), yearmonth("2020 May")), NA_real_, values))

dataf_tsible <- 
  as_tsibble(dataf, index = time, key = state)

dataf_tsible  
#> # A tsibble: 24 x 3 [1M]
#> # Key:       state [4]
#>        time state values
#>       <mth> <chr>  <dbl>
#>  1 2020 Jan CA     1.37 
#>  2 2020 Feb CA    -0.565
#>  3 2020 Mar CA    NA    
#>  4 2020 Apr CA    NA    
#>  5 2020 May CA    NA    
#>  6 2020 Jun CA    -0.106
#>  7 2020 Jan NY    -1.39 
#>  8 2020 Feb NY    -0.279
#>  9 2020 Mar NY    NA    
#> 10 2020 Apr NY    NA    
#> # ℹ 14 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>